# Unable to receive the UDP response from device

Tags: java, spring, udp, spring-integration

I'm trying to send the UDP request and receive the response. Spring Integration has the appropriate instruments for such kind of task: `UnicastSendingMessageHandler` and `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter`. I configured it in the following way

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public UnicastSendingMessageHandler unicastSendingMessageHandler() {
    UnicastSendingMessageHandler unicastSendingMessageHandler = new UnicastSendingMessageHandler("239.255.255.250", 1982);
    return unicastSendingMessageHandler;
}

@Bean
public UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter unicastReceivingChannelAdapter() {
    UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter unicastReceivingChannelAdapter = new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(8080);
    unicastReceivingChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
    return unicastReceivingChannelAdapter;
}
```

How I send a message (I'm using **sendDiscoveryMessage()** wherever I want):

```
@Service
public class DiscoveryService {

    private static final String DISCOVERY_MESSAGE = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            + "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1982\r\n"
            + "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n"
            + "ST: wifi_bulb";

    private final MessageChannel requestChannel;

    public DiscoveryService(final MessageChannel requestChannel) {
        this.requestChannel = requestChannel;
    }

    public void sendDiscoveryMessage() {
        requestChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>(DISCOVERY_MESSAGE));
    }
}
```

At this point, I can check the packets via WireShark and [ensure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pw9Z.png) that Datagram was sent and the appropriate response was sent too.
The only question is how to receive this response. As far as I understand reading the documentation, I need the method annotated with `@ServiceActivator`. But I don't understand where (which channel) I should receive the response (in order to correctly specify `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="")`). Also, I'm not sure about `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")` I put for `UnicastSendingMessageHandler` bean.
I tried to create the following method(assuming that the response will come to the same channel):

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public void receiveResponse(Message<String> response) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

but it actually intercepts my own request message (seems logical to me, because I send the request to **requestChannel**).
So I don't understand how many channels I need (maybe I need 1 for request and 1 for response) and how to create `@ServiceActivator` to catch the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unicastReceivingChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
```

You are sending the result to `nullChannel` which is like `/dev/null` on Unix; you are discarding it.

Use `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replyChannel")` and

```
unicastReceivingChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("replyChannel");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Changed. But now I figured out that actually my `unicastReceivingChannelAdapter` is configured to listen for the response on port 8080. But Wireshark tells me that the response was sent to the same port as a port of requester.I mean, if my discovery message was sent from port 41300, so the response will come to port 41300. So now I have to figure out how to configure this port "dynamically"

Comment: How can I configure `socket-expression` as it is said [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#advanced-outbound-configuration) using Java Config?

Comment: It's quite common to echo the reply on the same port; use `unicastSendingMessageHandler.setSocket(new DatagramSocket(8080));`

Comment: but `setSocket` has a `protected` modifier, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry (I tested it in the same package :) ). Use `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8080);
  handler.setSocketExpression(new FunctionExpression<>(msg -> socket));`

Comment: Actually, doing this led to `failed to create DatagramSocket; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` and as far as I understand it is because `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter` is created like `= new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(8080)` i.e using the same port. I tried another approach : `unicastSendingMessageHandler.setSocketExpressionString("@unicastReceivingChannelAdapter.socket")` and now it works. Thank you very much for your help with such stupid questions!